# discord.py How to use 2 unneeded arguments if the 1st isn't used and the 2nd is?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create an inventory command for my bot with a page argument and a user argument which both aren't necessary.

For example these commands sent could work:

```
!inventory
!inventory 2
!inventory @user
!inventory @user 3
```

```
@bot.command(name="inventory")
async def inventory(ctx, user: discord.Member=None, page: int=None):
  print(user.id)
  print(page)
```

The problem is that in the second case given, 2 will be the user giving an error instead of making 2 the page. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split up the arguments of the command. To check for the user, you can use the [mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) attribute from [discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message) which returns a list of Users.

```
@bot.command(name="inventory")
async def inventory(ctx, *, user=None, page=None):
  if mentions := ctx.message.mentions: # Takes the mentions in the command call
    await ctx.send(f"User's id is {mentions[0].id}") # Uses the first mention
    
  split_message = ctx.message.content.split()
  if split_message[-1].isdigit(): # Checks if last param is a digit
    await ctx.send(f'The page is {split_message[-1]}')
```

The argument `page` is technically useless but it will show up as an argument if you use `help inventory`.

`!help inventory` would return

```
!inventory

Arguments:
  user No description given (default: None)
  page No description given (default: None)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of optional arguments, they will be consumed in the defined order.
Therefore, it is not possible that the same argument can be used to fill its `user` or `page` parameter. You just ration. How would your bot know which parameter it should fill with that argument?

Anyway, the first argument will always be used to fill in the first parameter (`user`) and the second, to fill in the second argument (`page`). The only difference with an optional argument is that it can be suppressed.

To work around this situation, I strongly recommend that you convert your command to an Application Command (also called a [Slash Command](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f)). In this type of command the user can select which optional parameters he wants to use.

However, if for some reason you want to keep using text commands, the only way to make it possible for the same argument to be used by different optional parameters is by defining your own usage rule. One way to do this is to receive all the user arguments in a list of strings, without performing any type of conversion in the command definition:

```py
from discord.ext import commands


@bot.command(name="inventory")
async def inventory(ctx: commands.Context, *args: list[str]):
    # In this way all arguments will be received through the args list
    
    # parsing the arguments to set the command's parameters
    if args and args[-1].isdigit():
        # the last argument will be consumed by the page
        page = int(args[-1])
        del args[-1]  # deleting the last argument
    else:
        page = 1
    if args:
        # there are still arguments left, which are about the user
        username = " ".join(args)
        user = await commands.MemberConverter().convert(ctx, username)
    else:
        user = ctx.author
        
    
    print(user.id)
    print(page)
```